# jquery fade out sliding left

Tags: jquery, css

I want to make some divs fade out and sliding left at the same time, which is much like dismissing notification cards on Android.

I searched and found some jquery codes.

```
$('#clickme').click(function(){   
$('#book').animate({
      opacity: 'hide', // animate slideUp
      margin: 'hide',
      padding: 'hide',
      height: 'hide' // animate fadeOut
    }, 'slow', 'linear', function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

but this code makes the div(#book) fade out with sliding up, not left (or right).
I read the document about .animate() but I couldn't find how to do that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

check if this helps you

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#flip").click(function(){
        $("#panel").hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
    });
});
```

```css
#panel, #flip {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #e5eecc;
    border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}

#panel {
    padding: 50px;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
<div id="flip">Click to slide left panel</div>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can try this :

```js
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#book').animate({
    opacity: 0, // animate slideUp
    marginLeft: '-200px'
  }, 'slow', 'linear', function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='clickme'>Click me!!!</button>
<div id='book' style='width:200px; height:200px; background:black; border:greenyellow 4px solid;position:absolute; top:40px;'>Book</div>
```

---

### Note:

The target element which should be animated has to be positioned `relatively/absolutely`.

Answer (score 5):

If all you want is a fade out & slide left at the same time, you'll need to remove the margin, padding & height options as they will cause the animation to slide up *and* left.  You also need to apply the right option to have it slide out of the way:

```
$('#clickme').click(function(){   
$('#book').animate({
      opacity: 'hide', // animate slideUp
      right: '200px',  // slide left
    }, 'slow', 'linear', function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

I think you also need to apply the position:relative property to the #book element, and encase it in a parent element which has the position:relative property for this to work.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ch3uexcn/

Answer (score 2):

See http://jsfiddle.net/wnu734dz/

Width for slide left, opacity for fadeOut:

```
$('#book').animate({
      opacity: 'hide', // animate fadeOut
      width: 'hide'  // animate slideLeft
    }, 'slow', 'linear', function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to animate the width with

```
.animate({width: 'toggle'})
```